# Почему результат сложения двух массивов не записывется в третий массив?

Tags: c++

Вот код

```
 int result[lengthoftext];

 int j = 0;
 
 for(int item: result)
 {
    item = ASCIIsymkey[j] + ASCIIsymtext[j];
    if(item > 127)
    {
         item -= 127;
    }

    j++;
 }
```

А вот показания дебагера

```
result {-7632, 32767, 1431655832, 21845}
ASCIIsymkey {116, 101, 120, 116}
ASCIIsymtext {116, 101, 120, 116}
lengthoftext 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому что вы не запиcываете.

```cpp
int result[lengthoftext];
for(int j=0; j<lengthoftext; ++j){
    int item = ASCIIsymkey[j] + ASCIIsymtext[j];
    if(item>127)
        item -= 127
    result[j] = item;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло